# Selenium with Java use split() method with multiple delimiters

Tags: java, selenium

url - https://www.etmoney.com/mutual-funds/equity/focused/77

On the particular website I have to scape all the fund size and add all up and compare it later using Testng assertions.
Challenge being that there are multiple delimiter on fund size (₹ , and space) 3 delimiters

for ex:(scraped fund size)

₹110 Crs

₹8,696 Crs

₹3,460 Crs

₹711 Crs

₹5,990 Crs

₹26,218 Crs

₹7,907 Crs

₹1,780 Crs

₹956 Crs

₹1,708 Crs

₹1,330 Crs

₹5,825 Crs

₹18,712 Crs

Final output e like

```
110 
8696
3460
711
5990
26218
7907
1780
956 
1708
1330
5825
18712
```

```
int total = 0;
        List<WebElement> totalFunds = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class='card-bordy']/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div/p[2]"));

for(int i=0;i<totalFunds.size();i++) {
            String funds = totalFunds.get(i).getText();
            String fu = funds.split(" ")[0];
            System.out.println(fu.split("₹")[1]);
```

Error - "java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 1 out of bounds for length 1"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a regex replacement/capture approach here:

```java
int total = 0;
List<WebElement> totalFunds = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class='card-bordy']/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div/p[2]"));

for (int i=0;i < totalFunds.size(); i++) {
    String funds = totalFunds.get(i).getText();
    String fu = funds.replaceAll(".*?(\\d{1,3}(?:,\\d{3})*).*", "$1");
    System.out.println(fu);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your *xpath selector* can be simplified and made more robust with the *css selector* `By.cssSelector(".fund-size .fund-amount")`.

And the value *₹3,460 Crs* can be converted to a number with help of `java.text.DecimalFormat` class.

```
List<WebElement> elements = driver
        .findElements(By.cssSelector(".fund-size .fund-amount"));

DecimalFormat format = new DecimalFormat("₹###,### Crs");

for (WebElement element : elements) {
    Number number = format.parse(element.getText());
    System.out.println(number);
}
```

But take in mind that `parse` method throws the `ParseExteption` exception.